# OutOfMemory or GC Overhead with XSSF

Tags: java, xssf

Currently we are using XSSF for exporting records stored in DB to excel and download it. As per our requirement, we need to allow user to download 3 million records.

With XSSF, we are facing OutOfMemoryError:GC overhead limit exceeded.

I did some research and came to know that XSSF is hungry of memory. Can some one suggest me on better way to achieve my requirement. Please note that I need to download the data in excel format and dont want to write explicitly to any disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GC overhead limit exceeded with Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368612/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-with-apache-poi)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [POI API](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html).
We have successfully implemented streaming with large excel files in our programms using the POI API. It is important to keep the row size that is kept in memory low, the rest is basically done on disk then.

You can also set: SXSSFWorkbook.setCompressTempFiles, to prevent the temporary XML files from growing to large on disk.

With flushRows() you can manually flush rows to disk.

However, this is slower. But if memory is a constraint the only option.

Keep in mind that some methods, access rows implicitly. If those rows already have been swapped to disk you will encounter errors also I believe the API is only for writing large excel files.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(); 
        wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);

        SXSSFSheet sh = (SXSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);
        sh.setRandomAccessWindowSize(100);// keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk, this is also the default
        for(int i=  1; i < 100000; i++){
          Row row = sh.createRow(i);  // do something with the row
        }
    }
```