# JNA versus POI theoretical performance

Tags: java, performance, apache-poi, jna

Assuming few have benchmarked both JNA and Apache POI in terms of performance, which would be theoretically superior in terms of performance?

Looking into MS Excel parsing and/or building only. I've forked the JNA project and have been using that, but POI seems to be used with Excel much more and am curious if either has performance benefits, theoretically speaking.

If anyone has experience with both or benchmarked, even better. May try this myself at some point as well.

Comment: Both are not comparable. `Apache poi` is able creating or using `Excel` files without the need of an installed `Excel` application or native shared `Windows` libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Theoretically*, you could get faster performance directly implementing C API functions using JNA.

Note that I'm referring to direct C API implementation, not the use of the existing COM-based implementation.

For this theoretical performance improvement you would have to implement those C functions yourself.  You would incur a small processing overhead for the Java to Native layer but if you could design your code to minimize the Java/Native calls it's possible that you could create code which would be better at a particular task.

The existing Excel implementation in JNA is:

- Windows only
- A User-contributed implementation, not part of core JNA
- Relies on the COM layer, which is slower than the direct C API, and probably slower than POI
- Hasn't been updated recently which indicates it isn't as optimized as Apache Poi, which is under continuous development

So theoretically, you *will, on average,* and probably in most cases, get better performance with Apache POI than the existing JNA COM-based code.  You will also gain the advantage of a cross-platform, much more widely tested, implemented, and optimized library.

Theoretically, you *can* get better performance on a specific platform at a specific task by directly implementing C functions via JNA.

Comment: The view that a C API will be faster than Java is too simple, especially in situations where a lot of calls will be be made between Java code and native code, performance will likely decrease compared to a pure Java solution. Add the benefits of JIT, and the only you can only really say "it's complicated".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's why I said "can" and not "will", and qualified "specific platform/specific task".  Theoretically, at least.

Comment: Very interesting! The JNA project is updated often, but the 'implementations' are hard to use and are incomplete. Had to fork and include more COM functionality as mentioned above. It's understandable COM is slower, I've heard that too from a POC at work. So far JNA suits my needs and will need to use some C/C++ API within the month in parallel.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/programming-with-the-c-api-in-excel details the MS-based options.Heard POI is'memory-hungry'however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368612/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-with-apache-poi

Comment: The "implementations" are user-contributed and incomplete... remember this is an open source project relying on user contributions!  The core project is pretty good and capable of directly mapping your own functions.  The COM based Office stuff, as you've observed, is more of a proof of concept than intended "one size fits all" solution that POI is.  If you've forked and added, perhaps you can help contributing back what you've improved!

Comment: Oh definitely, 'hard to use and...incomplete' sounds like an insult to the JNA folks. By design, the implementations were Demos, so they weren't meant to be complete. Sorry about that. Matthias B. did say he had a COMTypelibraries repo which could be used in conjunction with JNA. I also setup a JNA dev environment but the build kept failing in some Windows Networking example if I remember correctly. Spent a few hours and ran out of time. My changes work without integrating them with the other packages. May revisit this!